# How to select the Column from csv file from the folder?

Tags: python, pandas, file, export-to-csv, glob

I am trying to select "column 3" from my files and then combine them into one file.  The issue is While I am combing the columns, they are not in the same pattern as files are in the folder. For Example, I have three files in the folder "First, Second and Third". My code given below is always reading the "Second" file before the "First" file. Can Anyone help me?

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
extension = 'dat'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index = np.arange(1394521), columns = ["velocity-magnitude"])
for i,f in tqdm(enumerate(all_filenames)):
    reader = pd.read_csv(f, sep=r"\s+")    
    col = reader.iloc[:,[3]]
    frames = [df,col]
    df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1,join="outer")
    df.to_csv('combined.dat', mode='a', header = False, index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob` uses `os.listdir` internally. This explains the arbitrary order of the files. In case you want some specific sorting, then you will have to apply it yourself, e.g. using `sorted(glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NYC Coder, yeah this sorted function is the solution to my problem.